# Is there a method for calculating all active shipping method prices for a given cart in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, shopware

It seems that Shopware is only really interested in calculating the price of the currently selected shipping method, which leaves the customer unable to know the price of a shipping method when choosing.

Is there a service that would let me calculate the prices of all active shipping methods for a given cart, or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked Shopware themselves and they recommended using `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Delivery\DeliveryCalculator::calculate` which is what calculates the shipping costs on a cart with a given shipping method.

The cart can be cloned and each shipping method applied to the deliveries (`$cart->getDeliveries()`) on the clone, to not mess with the actual cart. Once the price has been calculated, the total shipping price can be received using `$cart->getDeliveries()->getShippingCosts()->sum()`.

Comment: How can we use this? By overriding?